# OpenGL rendering - a window out ot the screen

Tags: linux, opengl, glsl, x11

When I draw a triangle and part (or whole) of that primitive is placed outside a viewing volume OpenGL performs clipping (before rasterization). That is described for example here: [link](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut05%20Boundaries%20and%20Clipping.html) What happens when a part of the window is placed outside the screen (monitor) ? What happens if I use compositing window manager (on linux, for example compiz) and the whole OpenGL window is placed on virtual desktop (for example a wall of the cube) which is not visible ? What happenns in that OpenGL application ? Is there any GPU usage ?  What about redirecting content of that window to the offscreen pixmap ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I draw a triangle and part (or whole) of that primitive is placed outside a viewing volume OpenGL performs clipping (before rasterization).

Clipping is a geometrical operation. When it comes to rasterization, everything happens on the pixel level.

It all comes down to Pixel Ownership.

In a plain, not composited windowing system, all windows share the same screen framebuffer. Each window is, well, a window (offset + size) into the screen framebuffer. When things get drawn to a window, using OpenGL or not, for every pixel it is tested if this pixel of the framebuffer actually belongs to the window; if some other, logical (and visible) window is in front, the pixel ownership tests will fail for these pixels and nothing gets drawn there (so that the window in front doesn't get overdrawn). That's why in a plain, uncomposited environment you can "screenshot" windows overlaying your OpenGL window with glReadPixels, because effectively that part of the framebuffer handed to OpenGL actually belongs to another window, but OpenGL doesn't know this.

Similarly, if a window is moved partially or completely off screen, the off-screen pixels will fail the pixel ownership test and nothing gets drawn there.

> What happens if I use compositing window manager

Then every window has its very own framebuffer, which it completely owns. Pixel Ownership tests will never fail. You figure the rest.

> What happenns in that OpenGL application?

To OpenGL it looks like all the pixels pass the ownership test when rasterizing. That's it.

> Is there any GPU usage?

Pixel ownership test is so important, that even long before there were GPUs, the first generation of graphics cards did have the functionality required to implement pixel ownership tests. The function is easy to implement and hardwired so there's no difference with that regard.

However the more pixels *fail* the test, i.e. are not being touch, the less the GPU has to work in rasterization stage, to rendering throughput actually increases if the window is obscured or partially moved off-screen in a non-composited environment.